# TatukGIS DK Scale Bar

Tags: gis, c++builder, vcl, tatukgis

How can I display the scale bar for my GIS Viewer? Apparently its not showing even if I already set the GIS Viewer property on my Scale bar. I also checked if its visible and it is set to true.

An alternative that I though of is printing it to an image but its only working if both the GIS Viewer and Scale bar are printed. And it look bad because its covering the map at the center.

Would it be accurate to use a static image using actual image size without streching as a scaling bar?

Here is the code for my alternative solution:

```
GIS->PrintBmp(Image1->Picture->Bitmap);
GIS_ControlScale1->PrintBmp(Image1->Picture->Bitmap, GIS->Scale);
```

I would prefer to have the first issue to be solve but if its not possible can anybody help me with an alternative solution? I just need the scale bar for the reports (tracing paper).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Control Scale will only show if the shape file's Coordinate System was set.

For alternative solution, I put the control scale on the clipboard first then to the image.